# How to read out a value from a txt and add it to a drop down list in php?

Tags: php, list, drop-down-menu

I write out each line from a txt file where the word 'free' can be found.

```
<?php
$filename = "data.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Couldn't open $filename");
while(!feof($fp))
{ $line = fgets($fp);
if (preg_match('/free/',$line)) // Print the line if it contains the word 'Ravi'
print "$line<br>";
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I would like to add every lines with the word 'free' into a drop down list, where i can pick one and forward this vaule to my email. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Well, this is awkward. `// Print the line if it contains the word 'Ravi'`

Comment: please consider to acceppt an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do so.

Add some echo statements as follows:

```
$filename = "data.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Couldn't open $filename");
echo "<select>";      //  THIS ONE
while(!feof($fp)) {
  $line = fgets($fp);
  if (preg_match('/free/',$line))
    echo "<option>" . $line . "</option>";   // THIS ONE
}
echo "</select>";         // AND THIS ONE
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

just build a select-element by php and feed it with `$line`:

```
// after $fp = fopen...
$h = '<select name="aname" id="aname">';

// within your while-loop    
$h .= '<option value="'.$line.'">'.$line.'</option>';

// after your while-loop
$h .= '</select>';

echo $h;
```